# Show Custom Taxonomy title in loop

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm using the code below to show the featured image and link for the first post in each custom taxonomy for a custom post type. I'd like to display the name of the custom taxonomy next to each image, but despite best efforts I can't find the way to do this. I only want to show the current taxonomy that is being queried. Any ideas?

```
        $post_type = 'prints';

        // Get all the taxonomies for this post type
        $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );

        foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) : 

            // Gets every "category" (term) in this taxonomy to get the respective posts
            $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );

            foreach( $terms as $term ) : 

                $posts = new WP_Query( "taxonomy=$taxonomy&term=$term->slug&posts_per_page=1" );

                if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="cat-preview">
                        <a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail ('medium'); ?></a>
                        <h2><!-- Looking to add custom taxonomy title here --></h2>
                    </div><?php
                endwhile; endif;

            endforeach;

        endforeach;
```

Comment: Do you mean name of taxonomy or term in taxonomy?

Comment: Sorry, yes, the name of the term in the taxonomy. G.M. has given a nice simple answer below which works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the current **taxonomy term** is in the `name` property of the `term` object, so, in your loop just `echo` it:

```
if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); ?>

<div class="cat-preview">
  <a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail ('medium'); ?></a>
  <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
</div><?php endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: You are a legend. Perfectly simple when you know how. Thanks!